# Change Excel column name with Python

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe

After several code attempts, I can't change the name of the columns on my excel documents.

```
import pandas as pd

FichierCible = r'C:\Users\User\Desktop\User\stack.xlsx'

df = pd.read_excel(FichierCible)
df.rename(columns={'a': 'A', 'b': 'B'}, inplace=True)
df

print(df)
```

> Empty DataFrame

> Columns: [A, B, c, d, e]

> Index: []

The change is displayed correctly on the command prompt but on the Excel document the change is not applied.
Do you have an idea ?

Thank you

Comment: Try to call `df.to_excel` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to write back your DataFrame to a new/the same Excel.

```py
df.to_excel(FichierCible)
```